# Follow-up on Nair/Tetali's Correlation Decay Tree for hypergraphs?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, approximation-algorithms, counting-complexity, hypergraphs

I'm wondering if anybody has followed up on Nair/Tetali's [correlation decay](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701494) tree construction for hypergraphs. I didn't find anything relevant in back-citation on google scholar. Interesting question are:

1. applying it to exact and approximate inference in Boltzmann machines, and
2. using it to determine for which hypergraphs it is tractable to count the number of colorings approximately.